# Git Branch and Hashref awareness during runtime using MS build

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I want to read git Head value and Hash ref value from refs/heads/Branchname and store them into a file path.

I am able to read the value and store them into file Now here is what I want

1. the thing is I want to split the .git/Head file value and want to store only Branch name from output for example, I am getting value from .git/Head as ref: refs/heads/BranchName but I need only BranchName so How to split this output stored into @(PathToHashRef)
2. I want to read the .git/Head file without passing hard coded Path.
3. Also the BranchName in the path I want to pass from spited value from point number 1

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PathToHashRefs Include="D:/Project/ProjectName/.git/refs/heads/BranchName"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Below is my code that I am using

```
  <Target Name="OutputGitVersion" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <GitHeadFile Include="D:/Project/ProjectName/.git/HEAD"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PathToHashRefs Include="D:/Project/ProjectName/.git/refs/heads/BranchName"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ReadLinesFromFile
          File="@(GitHeadFile)" >
      <Output
            TaskParameter="Lines"
            ItemName="PathToHashRef"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>

    <ReadLinesFromFile
        File="@(PathToHashRefs)" >
      <Output
            TaskParameter="Lines"
            ItemName="GitHashRef"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <WriteLinesToFile
        File="$(OutputPath)\git_info"
        Lines="@(PathToHashRef);@(GitHashRef)"
        Overwrite="true"
        Encoding="Unicode"/>
  </Target>
```

I have tried below solution for spilt but that did not worked

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Split>$(PathToHashRef.Split('/'))</Split>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: When you split the string "ref: refs/heads/BranchName" an array is returned. You want the third element of the array: "BranchName". Try `<Split>$(PathToHashRef.Split('/')[2])</Split>`

Comment: If I use it this way it is giving index out of range exception, I guess split is not working here that is why

Comment: The index out of range indicates that ‘PathToHashRef’ has less than two ‘/‘ characters.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to solve it myself below is the code.

```
<Target Name="OutputGitVersion" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <RootPath>$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove($(MSBuildThisFileDirectory), '.git/index'))</RootPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <GitHeadFile Include="$(RootPath)\.git\HEAD"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ReadLinesFromFile
              File="@(GitHeadFile)" >
        <Output
            TaskParameter="Lines"
            ItemName="PathToHashRef"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <FileContent>@(PathToHashRef)</FileContent>
        <Split>$(FileContent.Split('/')[2])</Split>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PathToHashRefs Include="$(RootPath)\.git\refs\heads\$(Split)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ReadLinesFromFile
          File="@(PathToHashRefs)" >
        <Output
            TaskParameter="Lines"
            ItemName="GitHashRef"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>

    <WriteLinesToFile
          File="$(OutputPath)\git_info"
          Lines="@(GitHashRef);$(Split)"
          Overwrite="true"
          Encoding="Unicode"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).